# C-programming, storing data from a for loop

Tags: c, loops, variables

```
scanf("%d", &N);

for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {

    scanf("%d", &a);
}

printf("%d", a);
```

If `N` is bigger than 1, how do I add up the values inputed in each of the loop iterations?

for example.. If N is 2, the scanf will scan twice, and I want the 2 "a" I inputed to add up

Comment: Thank you all for the fast answers to my noob question :D

Answer (score 2):

```
int sum = 0;
scanf("%d", &N);
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    scanf("%d", &a);
    sum = sum + a;
}

printf("%d", sum);
```

Now you have a sum variable with 0 value. In your for loop, you go on adding to last value of sum with a and at the end you print sum value.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new variable and add `a` from the loop so that each inputted value is added up:

```
int sum=0;

scanf("%d", &N);

for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    scanf("%d", &a);
    sum+=a;         //this is the short for sum=sum+a;
}

printf("The Sum is %d", sum);
```